# Angular Routing Parameters Remain The Same

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, routes

I created a button which directs the user to an overview page with a parameter "Id".
This works once but when you go back and select a different user it remains the same parameter that's been selected the first time. Is this a caching issue and if so what can I do about it?

```
 <button mat-button class="button" [routerLink]="'/user/overview'" [queryParams]=" { Id: user?.Id }">
      Show User
  </button>
```

The URL has the correct Parameter but the component remains the same.

Comment: Do you see the query param change? If the requery param is changing the problem is your code to read the param is not being executed again. If it's not changing then the error is in the component that hosts this button.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving us enough information. It is probably up to component that is handing 'user/overview' route. You need to subscribe to this.route.queryParams in ngOnInit in component to get changed Id.